# Family permit UK

Tags: visas, uk

I want to travel to the UK to stay with my mom. She has been in the UK for the past 2 years. I want to made an appointment as I have all the documents but I am experiencing a little bit of confusion. My mom send me the contract for work she has, but next week that contract will go off for she is switching jobs. Is that contract still good or should she send me the new one she will receive so I can have proof of work for her?

Answer (score 2):

To be eligible for an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/eea-family-permit) you need to prove that your EEA family member is: "working, looking for work, self-employed, studying or self-sufficient".

An employment contract that has expired will not suffice for that proof. It would be a very good idea to submit proof that she is changing jobs. The new employment contract would suffice, but you could also submit the offer letter (or pay slips, but presumably she has not yet been paid by a job she has not yet started).

I would submit both the old employment contract and some proof of the new job, to show that she has been working and will continue to do so.